# Improving Run Time for deduping lists based on only certain columns in Python

Tags: python, performance, list, deduplication

I have csv two files. I'm trying to remove all rows where certain columns match. I thought I'd use lists in Python to do this. I thought it'd be fast, but it's running way too slow.

I only want to compare the first 3 columns as the last 2 are unreliable. Yet, I want to export the last 2 columns.

Example:

```
A = [
(Jack, Smith, New York, USA, 100),
(Jim, Doe, Cleveland, UK, 200),
(Frank, Johnson, Chicago, USA, 300)
]

B = [
(Jack, Smith, New York, United States, blank),
(Jerry, Smith, Cleveland, USA, blank),
(Frank, Johnson, Chicago, America, blank)
]

Matched List = [
(Jack, Smith, New York, USA, 100)
(Frank, Johnson, Chicago, USA, 300)
]

Desired List = [
(Jim, Doe, Cleveland, UK, 200)
]
```

So I wrote two nested For Loops to compare the two lists and remove matched items. However, my list A is ~50,000 and list B is 600,000 rows. This is taking 3.5 hours. I need to run it on a set of 300,000 and 4,000,000 rows; but after seeing how long this takes it will run for days.

Here's the two For Loops (I'm comparing columns 0, 7, 9, and 10.)

```
for Acquisition_row in Acquisition_list[:]:
    for Leads_row in Leads_list:
        if (Acquisition_row[0] == Leads_row[0]) and (Acquisition_row[7] == Leads_row[7]) and (Acquisition_row[9] == Leads_row[9]) and (Acquisition_row[10] == Leads_row[10]):
            try:
                Acquisition_list.remove(Acquisition_row)
                Leads_list.append(Acquisition_row)
            except:
                print("Error!")
```

Is there any way to speed this up? Is there a better approach? Should I use a different programming language? Maybe upload these to a temp table in SQL db and use SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a `set()` or a `dict()` to keep track of the ones you've seen before. Looking up an item in a list is O(n), looking it up in a hashtable is O(1).

Comment: You say that you want to remove _all_ rows for which the first 3 columns match, but your desired output includes those rows that _do_ match on the first 3 columns, but not the 2 that do not match. Can you clarify that? Also, is it always the case that the values for the last 2 columns supplied in file A are the ones to use?

Comment: @kindall I'm not sure how I'd use the set() and dict() to cut down on the ones I've viewed already, the loops should iterate through, correct?

Comment: What about `(Jerry, Smith, Cleveland, USA, blank)` from file B? Would that record go in the matched list or the desired list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kindall is correct in suggesting `set()` or `dict` to keep track of what you've seen so far.

```
def getKey(row):
    return (row[0], row[7], row[9], row[10])

# create a set of all the keys you care about
lead_keys = {getKey(r) for r in Leads_rows}

# save this off due to reverse indexing gyration
len_ac_list = len(Acquisition_list)

for i, ac_row in enumerate(Acquisition_list[::-1]):
    ac_key = getKey(ac_row)
    if ac_key in lead_keys:   ## this look up is O(1)
        index = len_ac_list - i - 1
        Acquisition_list.pop(index)
        Leads_list.append(ac_row)
        ## maybe: lead_keys.add(ac_key)
```

The benefits are: you only iterate over Leads_list once, when creating your set of keys (I chose Leads_list for this because it's the larger list, so will save you more time); and your look-up for Acquisition_list takes constant time, O(1) rather than O(n) where n is len(Leads_list).

In your original setup, you were doing, at worst, (n*m) or (300000*4000000) operations which is... a ton. With `set`s, you will only do (n+m) or (30000+4000000) which is ...way fewer. Like 300,000 times fewer. That's the difference between 1.2 trillion things and .000004 trillion (4 million) things.

Comment: It would be faster to do `for ac_index, ac_row in reversed(list(enumerate(Acquisition_list[:])))` to get the index so that instead of doing `Acquisition_list.remove(ac_row)` (has to scan list for object), you can do `del Acquisition_list[ac_index]`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that when writing up the answer but couldn't wrap my head around it without really jumping into a python session. I don't fully understand the OPs setup, so I wasn't quite sure what they wanted; I would probably at least have used `enumerate` in my for loop, to then `Acquisition_list.pop(i)`, though I don't know offhand if that's O(n) or O(1);  your solution sounds appropriate/correct as well

Comment: If you do `Acquisition_list.pop(i)` (or `del`), then you must enumerate in reverse. Otherwise, after each `.pop(i)`, your `i` will be pointing one more past the intended element because `.pop(i)` will shift everything after `i` left by one.

Comment: Yeah, I was just writing a comment asking about that, but that makes perfect sense; is it necessary to do `reverse(list(enumerate(...` though? With a little loss of clarity, I think you save a bunch of memory by not having to re-do so many transforms? Check the updated code to see if that makes sense. Thanks for your feedback though - very helpful and important!

Comment: `reversed(list(enumerate(...` is necessary in order to get the index and row in reverse order. Or you could do `for i in xrange(len(Acquisition_list) - 1, -1, -1): ac_row = Acquisition_list[i]` depending on how expensive making a shallow copy of `Acquisition_list` is.

Comment: Your updated method looks like it should work. Just a trivial note: if you're doing `Acquisition_list.pop(index)` and ignoring the returned result, you might as well just do `del Acquisition_list[index]`because `.pop()` returned the removed item, and `del` just deletes it.